# USB programmable Input device for repetitive boot command line use

Tags: macos, usb, keyboard

I need a tool to help me work more efficiently.

Task:
Boot Macbook into single user mode.
Type commands.
set macbook on shelf.
Grab another Macbook Repeat hundreds of times.

Is there some pre-made or home brew way of an auto input keyboard?
Perhaps use another computer to interface as a keyboard?
At this point I would look at a building a robot to physically punch the keys.(hopefully not ^_^)
BTW what i don't need are these batch or other based program's that input keystrokes in an OS environment, I need something that is recognized as a keyboard and inputs key strokes via USB.

Thank you for your time!